# When passing state through navigation my this.props.navigation.state is undefined?

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I try to pass parameters through my navigation. I can't seem to acces them. They keep on beeing undefined when I try to use them.

This is how I pass them:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('gamescreen',{gameDTO:message.body})
```

This is how I try to use them:

```
renderChat() {
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.gameDTO.gameId)
    return <Chat token={this.state.token} id={this.props.navigation.state.params.gameDTO.gameId}
                         name={this.state.username}/>
}
```

It keeps giving me TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state') when I acces it.

However in my console.log, it is not undefined and just shows the right String.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I'm fairly new to React Native.

Comment: This might be a context issue. Try assigning this.props.navigation.state.params.gameDTO.gameId to a new variable and then passing to the Chat component.

Comment: When putting in a variable it has the same effect. When I log it, it has the right value but when I pass it, it still gives the same error. Is accessing the state of the navigation maybe async and doesn't it load in time?

Comment: If it is async, it should give an error on console.log too. I still think it might be a context issue. The Chat component maybe can't evaluate this.props.navigation.state.params.gameDTO.gameId because it only exists in the parent. You can try putting this.props.navigation.state.params.gameDTO.gameId inside an arrow function that returns it (to bind the context). Then pass to the Chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the import of the chat component, that's why it could never recognize the navigation state. **All the statements in this thread work fine for passing parameters through navigation.** I just tab completed my Chat component and Webstorm didn't import the component from it's location, but imported it from a different screen I was using the component in.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, this is TypeError.
this.props.navigation doesn't have state object, which means undefined object.
Please refer to this link.
[enter link description here](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/navigate-with-params-v3)

Comment: Wouldn't the console.log give a TypeError then aswell?

Comment: If you want get route parameter, you can use as following.

 console.log(this.props.navigation.getParam('gameDTO', 'some default value'));

Answer (score 0):

The `renderChat()` method must be declared in your component's `constructor`  otherwise it will not have access to `this`.

```
constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.renderChat = this.renderChat.bind(this)
}

renderChat(){
   this.props.navigation.getParam('gameDTO', 'default') //returns id
}
```

Another solution is convert `renderChat()` into an arrow function

```
renderChat = () => {
    this.props.navigation.getParam('gameDTO', 'default') //returns id
}
```